# How to show agents (Pedestrians) which is inside another agent Floor 2 in Main agent?

Tags: anylogic

I have a model where I have an agent called Floor 2. And agent pedestrian fills up the floor 2 at a rate of 1 per second.

When I call floor 2 in main agent, the pedestrians dont show up. And the floor is empty.

Comment: Learn about "animating hierarchical models" in the help: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/presentation/animating-hierarchical-models.html#animating-hierarchical-models  . Specifically the section "To create an embedded presentation shape manually" is probably your issue right now

Comment: Thanks. But the problem was the arrival location was set to somewhere else outside of that specific floor. Once I made sure, the pedestrians were arriving on the specific floor then it worked like a charm.

Comment: awesome, feel free to post the full solution as an answer yourself below. Helps future people with similar problems :)